# Is it possible to specify starting item when rendering a PlantUML diagram?

Tags: plantuml

I used a tool to auto-generate a puml file from a large codebase. I can render the whole thing as an svg, but is it possible to render only part of the puml file?

Specifically, I have an interface `ICameraSetting` and I want to map out all interactions with it. The svg of the whole codebase is too big to comfortably work with, so I would like to tell the PlantUML jar to read the puml file and create an svg with just the `ICameraSetting` interface plus anything that interacts with or depends on it.

I know I can generate an interactive svg and click on the `ICameraSetting` component, but that just dims the other components instead of removing them from the view, so it doesn't make the svg any easier to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still can't find a direct way to do this, but I managed to get something equivalent by editing the svg to add a little extra functionality. Clicking an element now adds the "removed" class to anything that isn't selected to apply a `display:none` style, then it transforms all selected elements so they are as close to top-left as possible, and resizes the svg to fit just the selected elements.

Here's the code. I haven't included some of the boilerplate stuff or the elements, but it shouldn't be too difficult to add this to any interactive svg generated using PlantUML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii" standalone="no"?>
<svg id="svgElement" ... >
    <defs id="defsElement">
        <style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
            .elem.removed, .link.removed {display: none;}
        ]]></style>
        ...
        <script>
            ...
            function main() {

                let focusedSelect = true;
                let svgEl = document.getElementById('svgElement');
                let rootWidth = svgEl.style.width;
                let rootHeight = svgEl.style.height;
                var transformStyle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'style');
                transformStyle.type = 'text/css';
                document.getElementById('defsElement').appendChild(transformStyle);

                ...

                function clearSelected() {
                    selectedElems.forEach(item =&gt; {
                        item.classList.remove('selected');
                        if (focusedSelect) { item.classList.add('removed'); }
                    });
                    selectedElems = [];

                    selectedLinks.forEach(item =&gt; {
                        item.classList.remove('selected');
                        if (focusedSelect) { item.classList.add('removed'); }
                    });
                    selectedLinks = [];
                }

                function selectAll() {
                    svgEl.style.width = rootWidth;
                    svgEl.style.height = rootHeight;
                    svgEl.setAttribute('width', rootWidth);
                    svgEl.setAttribute('height', rootHeight);
                    svgEl.setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 ' + parseInt(rootWidth) + ' ' + parseInt(rootHeight));
                    transformStyle.textContent = '';

                    selectedElemName = null;

                    selectedElems = Array.from(elems);
                    selectedElems.forEach(item =&gt; {
                        item.classList.add('selected');
                        item.classList.remove('removed');
                    });

                    selectedLinks = Array.from(links);
                    selectedLinks.forEach(item =&gt; {
                        item.classList.add('selected');
                        item.classList.remove('removed');
                    });
                }

                function selectElem(elemName) {
                    if (elemName === selectedElemName) {
                        selectAll();
                    } else {
                        clearSelected();
                        selectedElemName = elemName;
                
                        elemsMap[elemName].classList.add('selected');
                        elemsMap[elemName].classList.remove('removed');
                        selectedElems.push(elemsMap[elemName]);
                
                        linkedElems[elemName].forEach(linkedElem =&gt; {
                            selectedElems.push(linkedElem);
                            linkedElem.classList.remove('removed');
                            linkedElem.classList.add('selected');
                        });
                
                        linkedLinks[elemName].forEach(linkedLink =&gt; {
                            selectedLinks.push(linkedLink);
                            linkedLink.classList.remove('removed');
                            linkedLink.classList.add('selected');
                        });
                
                        if (focusedSelect) {
                            window.requestAnimationFrame(function () {
                                let selectedRect = elemsMap[elemName].getBoundingClientRect();
                                let leftmost = { x: selectedRect.left + window.scrollX, y: selectedRect.top + window.scrollY };
                                let bottommost = { x: selectedRect.right + window.scrollX, y: selectedRect.bottom + window.scrollY };
                    
                                linkedElems[elemName].forEach(linkedElem =&gt; {
                                    let rect = linkedElem.getBoundingClientRect();
                                    if (rect.left + window.scrollX &lt; leftmost.x) { leftmost.x = rect.left + window.scrollX; }
                                    if (rect.top + window.scrollY &lt; leftmost.y) { leftmost.y = rect.top + window.scrollY; }
                                    if (rect.right + window.scrollX &gt; bottommost.x) { bottommost.x = rect.right + window.scrollX; }
                                    if (rect.bottom + window.scrollY &gt; bottommost.y) { bottommost.y = rect.bottom + window.scrollY; }
                                });
                    
                                linkedLinks[elemName].forEach(linkedLink =&gt; {
                                    let rect = linkedLink.getBoundingClientRect();
                                    if (rect.left + window.scrollX &lt; leftmost.x) { leftmost.x = rect.left + window.scrollX; }
                                    if (rect.top + window.scrollY &lt; leftmost.y) { leftmost.y = rect.top + window.scrollY; }
                                    if (rect.right + window.scrollX &gt; bottommost.x) { bottommost.x = rect.right + window.scrollX; }
                                    if (rect.bottom + window.scrollY &gt; bottommost.y) { bottommost.y = rect.bottom + window.scrollY; }
                                });
                    
                                let rootRect = svgEl.getBoundingClientRect();
                                let offset = { x: leftmost.x - (rootRect.left + window.scrollX), y: leftmost.y - (rootRect.top + window.scrollY) };
                                let newSize = { x: bottommost.x - leftmost.x, y: bottommost.y - leftmost.y };
                    
                                for (let i = 0; i &lt; transformStyle.sheet.cssRules.length; i++) { transformStyle.sheet.removeRule(i); }
                                transformStyle.sheet.insertRule('.elem.selected, .link.selected { transform: translate(-' + offset.x + 'px, -' + offset.y + 'px); }', 0);
                                svgEl.style.width = newSize.x + 'px';
                                svgEl.style.height = newSize.y + 'px';
                                svgEl.setAttribute('width', newSize.x + 'px');
                                svgEl.setAttribute('height', newSize.y + 'px');
                                svgEl.setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 ' + newSize.x + ' ' + newSize.y);
                                window.scrollTo(0,0);
                    
                                window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
                                    let selectedRectFinal = elemsMap[elemName].getBoundingClientRect();
                                    window.scrollTo(selectedRectFinal.x, selectedRectFinal.y);
                                });
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    
                }

            }

            ...

        </script>
    </defs>
    ...
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

> but is it possible to render only part of the puml file?

You didn't give a concrete example, so I'm making one up. `hide @unlinked` is documented at https://plantuml.com/class-diagram

```
@startuml
interface ICameraSetting 
class C1 implements ICameraSetting 
class C2
class C3

hide @unlinked
@enduml
```

Classes C2 and C3 don't show up because they're not linked to anything. My example is overly simplified, probably.

[image: PlantUML class diagram only showing classes that implement the interface.]

Another thing to try might be `!include`-ing commands to `hide` uninteresting interfaces so their links aren't added? See [this](https://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/NSwz2i9040JWVfzYh0GnXVe2mKBmCTQxZLdOsvFxqTUN10j9Cyp0LynO6vVMav5wap9n4DolNFxcBUSB1UDQbtg2ffT94czrbSSDE1CjYSCmh9veZpOBfcoMF-fF17Oy19OvIiHR6JlrO3qAQDRuEp2Anvxi2m00). Without a specific example, it's hard to give a specific answer.

Comment: The problem I'm facing is that the auto-generated puml file is >12,000 lines long. Every class is linked to *something*, so putting the command to hide unlinked classes won't remove much (if anything). I guess my question is: given a large puml file that would be too time-consuming to edit by hand, is there a way to tell PlantUML to start at ICameraInterface and automatically ignore anything not directly linked to it.

Comment: @Scutterman OK, I understand better. I've used similar code generating schemes for big diagrams. I found it best to put the logic in the code generator and just re-generate (and re-visualize). Here's a video https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=25YLePaExoQ (it doesn't show how it's done, but at each change of settings, the PlantUML code is re-generated and sent to the web service to get a PNG).

Comment: @Scutterman with complex diagrams, I don't see a PlantUML-only solution.

Comment: Thanks for the link, and for confirming my initial suspicions that this wasn't available in PlantUML natively. I think the tool I used is open source so there's a chance I can adapt it to generate the puml differently if I need this again. For now, the xml tweaks I posted in the other answer did the job I needed.